# Is there a machine learning model I should look into to predict the effect land topology will have on prevailing wind direction near bodies of water

Tags: machine-learning

I'd like to predict the change in wind velocity due to land near bodies of water. Warmer or colder land should change the wind velocity of nearshore breeze. I'd also like to predict wind shadows that may be present from land topology. Is there are particular machine learning model that I should look into for this?

This would be for hyper localized predictions. Less than 1 mile in resolution.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether your input is a picture or just features.

In the first case, you can implement a CNN: [they are often used by scientists](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/331557018_Convolutional_Neural_Network_for_Satellite_Image_Classification) in analyzing satellite images.

In the second case, I think the most simple idea is to look for a multivariate regression model, but it may not be that effective: you could also look for [kNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) or [Random Forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest).

Comment: input would be data. I know the prevailing wind velocity, land temperature, water temperature, land elevation, and topology.

Comment: Then, try with regression and then with the other algorithms I wrote above